# Is there a way to change header background when entering a specific fullscreen section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched and searched, with no luck, after a way to change header background when entering a specific fullscreen section.
I've found jquery solutions for divs with specific height, but nothing that I know how to apply to elements with height: 100vh and width: 100vw.

Is this possible?

```css
section {
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
    }
    #section-one {
        background-color:white;
    }
    #section-two {
        background-color:green;
    }
    #section-three {
        background-color:blue;
    }
    #section-four {
        background-color:orange;
    }
    header {
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
        height: 30px;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        z-index:1;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul li{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section-one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-four">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<section id="section-one"></section>
<section id="section-two"></section>
<section id="section-three"></section>
<section id="section-four"></section>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to modify header's background-color based on which div is in the viewport while scrolling or clicking on header's anchors ?

Comment: Exactly! I'm curious to know if it's possible with modifying the nav link color as well.

Comment: See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/ which I believe would solve your problem using a scroll event listener. You can always use pure javascript, no need for jQuery.

Comment: Media queries are useful when you want to modify your site or app depending on a device's general type (such as print vs. screen) or specific characteristics and parameters (such as screen resolution or browser viewport width).

Comment: I do not believe the problem here is a question of css and media styling, but container scrolling adjusting header's styles. Media queries will not help in this case...

Answer (score 1):

This could be an implementation using plain javascript and scroll event handler with minimal changes to your current html structure. This also supports clicking on anchor links..

```js
let activeHeader = null;

function setCurrentSection() {
  const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
  const scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  for(let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    const section = sections[i];
    const scrollDifference = section.offsetTop - scrollPosition;
    if(scrollDifference >= 0 && scrollDifference <= 30) {
      const headerSection = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${section.id}']`);

      if(headerSection !== activeHeader) {
        if(activeHeader) activeHeader.style.backgroundColor = "inherit";
        const sectionStyles = window.getComputedStyle(section);
        headerSection.style.backgroundColor = sectionStyles.backgroundColor;
        activeHeader = headerSection;
      }
    }
  }
}

setCurrentSection();

window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    setCurrentSection();   
}, false);
```

```css
section {
        height:100vh;
        width:100vw;
    }
    #section-one {
        background-color:white;
    }
    #section-two {
        background-color:green;
    }
    #section-three {
        background-color:blue;
    }
    #section-four {
        background-color:orange;
    }
    header {
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
        height: 30px;
        position:fixed;
        width:100%;
        top:0;
        z-index:1;
    }
    ul {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    ul li{
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a data-id="section-one" href="#section-one">One</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="section-two" href="#section-two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="section-three" href="#section-three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a data-id="section-four" href="#section-four">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<section id="section-one"></section>
<section id="section-two"></section>
<section id="section-three"></section>
<section id="section-four"></section>
```